# How to dynamically determine the control path after a post - asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have some JS code that is sitting inside a userControl. The userControl is sitting inside a content placeholder, and to make matters worse, the server side script could be reused from a number of pages in the future.

This JS is responsible for creating a post request to a page via JSON.

In I.E: the names of the elements are fine - for example Name, Surname, Address

But in Firefox I'm getting the prefix too of the server side controls.

For example:

ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_UserControl1_Name

ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_UserControl1_Surname

ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_UserControl1_Address

Once I have received the post values I'm hoping there is some clever way to determine the path of the controls dynamically, so I can get the real form element names.

Is this possible? This is a .net v2 solution so I am unable to just change config like I would if it was a v4 solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to stash away the `ClientID` property of the controls you want in a javascript object.

Comment: I have less control over the actual JS, and more control over the serverside script that processes the JSON request.